# jQuery & CSS - temporary placeholder for image when they are different sizes

Tags: jquery, css, timeout, placeholder

I am trying to build an image gallery where by I show a temporary image (a heart) for 1 second in place of the actual image (image 1, image 2 etc).

jsfiddle is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/tgzqLmma/

each image has the temporary heart img for it's src and the real image stored with `data-src` like so:

```
<div>
    <img class="delay" src="http://s12.postimg.org/4toxdafhl/heart.png" 
    data-src="http://placehold.it/260x280/E8117F/FFFFFF?text=image+1" alt=""     
    style="padding-top:120px; padding-bottom:120px"/>
</div>
```

I use padding top and bottom (will be dynamically defined server-side based on the images height) to vertically center the heart img inside the container.

Then in jQuery i remove the padding and switch the src with the data-src value after 1 second for each image:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function () {
       jQuery('.delay').each(function () {
          var imagex = jQuery(this);
          var imgOriginal = imagex.data('src');
          jQuery(imagex).removeClass('delay');
          jQuery(imagex).css('padding',0);
          jQuery(imagex).attr('src', imgOriginal);
        });
     }, 1000);
});
```

I use media queries and css to adjust the size of the main images and container.

My problem is that i need the heart image to stay at 40x40px but for then the main image that comes in after 1 second to be the correct size. At the moment in my jsfiddle you can see the first 2 images are exanding the heart image but i want it to look like the third image (i have deliberately not switched that one)

I know this is because I am setting the `width` and `max-width` in my css but can i change the code to allow this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of placing the placeholder in the image source itself, you can place it in the `background` of the image, which saves you some code as well. [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m75w5djw/)

Just add a `.placeholder` class to the image :

```
<img class="delay placeholder" src="" data-src="http://placehold.it/260x280/E8117F/FFFFFF?text=image+1" alt="" style="padding-top:120px; padding-bottom:120px"/>
```

Then the CSS for placeholder class :

```
div img.placeholder{
    background:url('http://s12.postimg.org/4toxdafhl/heart.png') center center no-repeat;
    display:block;
}
```

And some JavaScript code modification to remove the class :

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function () {
       jQuery('.delay').each(function () {
          var imagex = jQuery(this);
          var imgOriginal = imagex.data('src');
            jQuery(imagex).css('padding',0);
            jQuery(imagex).attr('src', imgOriginal);
            jQuery(imagex).removeClass('placeholder'); /*added this*/
       });
    }, 1000);
});
```